# c# infinite stream of text of characters and print them alphabetically

Tags: c#, string, sorting, alphabetical

how do I print a stream of text alphabetically by dynamically reading it in C#.

ex like: "automatically" as "aaacillmottuy"

for small strings we all know .sort() function will work. but what if we have very big stream of text and no unlimited memory

what am thinking is. read the stream of characters and for the length of that string/stream, iterate for finding letter "a" and increment variable ai++ starting with value ai=0. repeat this for 25 other alphabets. finally for the value of ai print "number of aaa's then bbb then cc..." this is the solution am thinking, fastest one by not consuming too much of memory.. unless if some one has other logic here

Comment: That's a good question - what have you tried?

Comment: Ask yourself: is it even possible?  You must "look ahead" at least one character to see if it comes "before" or "after" the previous.  What about the character after that? And the one after that?  How far must you "look ahead" to be sure the characters you've got so far are in the right order ... and it's never going to change?  *FORGET* about "C#" for a moment.  Think about the *ALGORITHM*.  And update your post with your thoughts :)

Comment: How is "automatically" infinite?

Comment: This is not a tutorial site.  You need to do some research, write some code and get back to us when you have a problem with your code

Comment: what am thinking is. read the stream characters and for the length of that string/stream, iterate for finding letter "a" and increment variable ai++ starting with 0. repeat this for 25 other alphabets. finally for number of ai print "aaa then bbb then cc..."  this is the solution am thinking, fastest one by not consuming too much of memory.. unless of some one has other logic here.

Answer (score 1):

```
string unsorted = yourStreamText;
string newString = new String(unsorted.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray());
```

newString will have the characters of your stream sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Why does it have to be a list?  Why build the string when you can pass a char array to the string constructor?  Also, this does not seem to address the OP’s vague “infinite stream” problem.

Comment: Arrays don't have the Sort() function.

Comment: @maccettura Also, I'm an idiot with for forgetting the string constructor. I edited. I think I've been up to long today lol.

Comment: true, but Arrays _are_ IEnumerable. Which grants you access to LINQ’s OrderBy.

Comment: [See here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7a1jR6) for an example of what I mean

Comment: @maccettura yea that's way cleaner and efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        var sorted = string.Empty;
        while (true)
        {
            var readChar = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            sorted = String.Concat((sorted + readChar).OrderBy(c => c));
            Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine} - Sorted input: {sorted}");
        }
    }
```